# UniswapV2 swapExactTokensForETH approve and transfer

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have tried to create a smart contract. I followed this tutorial to have uniswap swap examples https://cryptomarketpool.com/how-to-swap-tokens-on-uniswap-using-a-smart-contract/

Here one of my smart contract function in which I would like to swap some token amount for some eth.

```
  function swapTokenToEth(uint tokenAmount, uint amountOutMin) public {
    uint deadline = block.timestamp + 150;
    IERC20(token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenAmount);
    IERC20(token).approve(UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER, tokenAmount);
    uniswapRouter.swapExactTokensForETH(tokenAmount, amountOutMin, getPath(), msg.sender, deadline);
  }
```

I am calling this swap method from a Truffle test environment

```
await dex.swapTokenToEth(tokenAmount, amountOutMin {
  from: accounts[1],
});
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance -- Reason given: ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance.
```

I tried several things but now I am stuck and I don't understand this error.
Any hint on how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance*

This is a custom error message from a contract.

Based on the context, I'm assuming it's coming from the `token` contract's function `transferFrom()` (or another function called by this one), from a failed `require()` condition.

Which means that the `accounts[1]` (user executing the `swapTokenToEth()` function) haven't approved the `dex` contract to manipulate their tokens.

**Solution:** Before executing `dex.swapTokenToEth()`, you also need to execute `tokenContract.approve(dexAddress)` from the `accounts[1]` address. It's sufficient to execute the `approve()` function just once (unless you redeploy the contracts) with a sufficient amount - the approval decreases with each amount used in the `transferFrom()` function.